# Turning a Binary Tree into an Array of Structures in order to Order

Tags: c

I have an assignment in which I am supposed to scan a text file and store a list of words and their frequency in a binary tree. I successfully completed the first part and am able to have all the words in the tree with records of there frequency. As for the next part, I am supposed to print out the words and their frequency from most occurring word to least occurring word and any tiebreaker should be settled with alphabetical order. My professor hinted towards using an array of structures, which I am trying to implement, but I can't seem to figure out what it is I am doing wrong. I posted the code below, and I was wondering if someone could guide me towards a link or tutorial that would help me convert the binary tree into an array and then sort it based on frequency.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 50

typedef struct node
{
    int depth;
    int frequency;
    struct node *left, *right;
    char word[MAXSIZE];
} node;


node* insert(node *root, char newWord[MAXSIZE])
{
    node *temp;
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->frequency = 1;
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        strcpy(temp->word, newWord);
        root = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        if(strcmp(newWord, root->word)<0)
        {
            root->left = insert(root->left, newWord);
        }
        else if(strcmp(newWord, root->word)>0)
        {
            root->right =insert(root->right, newWord);
        }
        else if(strcmp(newWord, root->word)==0)
        {
            root->frequency +=1;
        }
    }
    return(root);
}

int findFreq(node *root, char findWord[MAXSIZE])
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(findWord, root->word)==0)
        {
            return root->frequency;
        }
        else if(strcmp(findWord, root->word)>0)
        {
            findFreq(root->right, findWord);
        }
        else if(strcmp(findWord, root->word)<0)
        {
            findFreq(root->left, findWord);
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}


int findDepth(node *root, char findWord[MAXSIZE])
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return -1;
    int dist = -1;
    if(strcmp(findWord, root->word)==0||(dist=findDepth(root->left, findWord))>=0||(dist = findDepth(root->right, findWord))>=0)
    {
        return dist+1;
    }
    return dist;
}

int countWords(node *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return 0;
    return 1+countWords(root->left) +countWords(root->right);
}

node *inOrder(node *root)
{
    if(root!= NULL)
    {
        inOrder(root->left);
        //printf("%s %d\n", root->word, root->frequency);
        return root;
        inOrder(root->right);
    }
}

void main()
{
    FILE *infile;
    FILE *outfile;
    char string[MAXSIZE];
    int freq, deep;
    int i, c, n, j, k, a;
    int x = 0;
    int arr[MAXSIZE];
    node *root = NULL;
    node *(heads[MAXSIZE]);
    infile = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    outfile = fopen("out.txt","w");
    fscanf(infile, "%d\n", &n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fscanf(infile, "%d %s\n", &c, string);
        switch (c)
        {
            case 1:
                root = insert(root, string);
                break;
            case 2:
                freq = findFreq(root, string);
                deep = findDepth(root, string);
                fprintf(outfile, "%d %d\n", freq, deep);
                printf("%d %d\n", freq, deep);
                break;
            default:
                printf("error in input\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    j = countWords(root);
    for(a=0;a<j;a++)
    {
        heads[a] = malloc(10 * sizeof **heads);
        heads[a] = inOrder(root);
        printf("%s %d\n", heads[a]->word, heads[a]->frequency);
        //inOrder(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using an in-order traversal of the tree to populate the array?  And you shouldn't need to perform any new allocations for that part -- there's no reason why you can't populate the array with pointers to the `node`s you already have.  You could use any other tree traversal too, but an in-order traversal would mean that you could get the wanted tie break from just performing a stable sort on the frequency, without taking alphabetical order explicitly into account.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry I should've uploaded a more updated code, but I currently I am using in-order traversal to populate the array, as I was hoping I could just sort the array after. The only problem is that the function I wrote doesn't seem to return the node value I want, instead it just keeps setting each pointer to the root node.

Comment: So, the updated code does perform an in-order traversal, but still no, that traversal does not populate the array.  For the traversal to populate the array would mean that the action performed when processing each node (in order) would include populating the appropriate element of the array.  Moreover, you're (still) performing unnecessary allocations and building an array that doesn't contain the frequency information that you want to sort on.  Following your professor's hint, make an array of the nodes themselves (or, better, pointers to them).

Comment: You will need to pass more arguments to the `inOrder()` function to use it to populate the array: at least a pointer (in)to the array. And you will need to track the next unfilled spot in the array, either via that function's return value or via an out parameter.